# React component losing focus

Tags: reactjs

I have a really simple react component that I want to save it as a string in a file and then evaluate it & show it in another component (EG: ComplexComponent). I've put side to side the original component & the component to string for you to see it's the same component.

Question: Does somebody know why the component/textbox created from the string is losing focus & how to fix it? I enter a character and then I have to click again on the textbox and so on and it's really annoying :-(

Code is also here (you can see live the problem): http://jsfiddle.net/jonattfin/s7fh1q9g/

```
var SimpleComponent = React.createClass({

    _changeAge: function(e) {
        this.props.changeAge(e.target.value);
    },

    render: function(){
        return  (
            <div >
                <input type='text' value={this.props.age} onChange={this._changeAge} />
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var ComplexComponent = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            age1: '',
            age2: ''
        };
    },

    _changeAge1: function(value) {
        this.setState({
            age1: value
        });
    },

    _changeAge2: function(value) {
        this.setState({
            age2: value
        });
    },

    render: function(){

        var simpleComponentString = "React.createClass({ displayName: 'SimpleComponent', _changeAge: function _changeAge(e) { this.props.changeAge(e.target.value); }, render: function render() { return React.createElement( 'div', null, React.createElement('input', { type: 'text', value: this.props.age, onChange: this._changeAge }) ); } });";
        var SimpleComponentFromString = eval(simpleComponentString);

        return  (
            <div>
                Age1:<br/>
                <SimpleComponent key='simpleComponent' age={this.state.age1} changeAge={this._changeAge1}/>
                Age2:<br/>
                <SimpleComponentFromString key='simpleComponentFromString' age={this.state.age2} changeAge={this._changeAge2}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: Please double check the formatting of your code.

Comment: It's the eval thing, you're creating a new component and throwing away the old one everytime. Never use eval and, why, for the love of god, are you creating your components like that?

Comment: @limelights: yes you are right, it's the eval thing, I've tested it and it's working. I'm creating components like that because it should work like plugins, the component string is stored in a file, i'm parsing it and render the component on the screen. Do I have other choice?

Comment: Keeping a consistent 'key' will fix this. But you are missing the concept of Composition in React. Please reference this: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html